# NullPointerException at getView method in Adapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to populate a ListView from a SQLite database. When I scroll to the ListView the application crashed and I get a `NullPointerException` in `getView()` in the adapter class. How to solve this issue?

Getting `NullPointerException` at this line:

```
holder.txtInIt.setText(followUp_List.getShortRGN());
```

Here is my adapter code.

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            final Holder holder;
            if (row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                row = vi.inflate(R.layout.follow_uplist_item, parent, false);
                holder = new Holder();

                holder.txtInIt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtInitialLetter);
                holder.txtUserName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_UserName);
                holder.txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_followDate);
                holder.txtFolloUp = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textFolloup);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
            }

            final FollowUp_List followUp_List = data.get(position);

            holder.txtInIt.setText(followUp_List.getShortRGN());
            if (holder.txtInIt.getText().toString().equals("R"))
            {
                holder.txtInIt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_circle_shape);
            }
            if (holder.txtInIt.getText().toString().equals("G")) {

                holder.txtInIt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_circle_shape);
            }
            if (holder.txtInIt.getText().toString().equals("N")) {

                holder.txtInIt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_circle_shape);
            }


            holder.txtUserName.setText(followUp_List.getCreatedBy());
            holder.txtDate.setText(followUp_List.getFollowup_date());
            holder.txtFolloUp.setText(followUp_List.getFollowUp());

            return row;

        }

        final class Holder {
            TextView txtInIt;
            TextView txtUserName;
            TextView txtDate;
            TextView txtFolloUp;
        }
    }
```

Here is the logcat information:

```
10-24 09:54:06.057    5826-5826/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.FollowUpList$FollowUpListAdapter.getView(FollowUpList.java:299)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2012)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:636)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4546)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:2852)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3106)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5486)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1953)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1714)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1728)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1840)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5662)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2863)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where do you set the tag to the `holder` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `holder` object is null. Hence the exception. So if `holder` is null, you need to initialize the `holder`.

Instead of `if (row == null)` ,  use `if (row == null || holder == null)`

Also, inside you`if` condition, you need to add `row.setTag(holder)`. This is important, only then you can perform the `getTag()`.

So it will be something like this:

```
            if (row == null || holder == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                row = vi.inflate(R.layout.follow_uplist_item, parent, false);
                holder = new Holder();

                holder.txtInIt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtInitialLetter);
                holder.txtUserName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_UserName);
                holder.txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_followDate);
                holder.txtFolloUp = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textFolloup);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your layout file, the same you have implemented to your adapter class and after that check your textview id is the same that you have added to your adapter class. I thought your textview id is different as the adapter class.

**Just replace the below code into your adapter class**

```
if (row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                row = vi.inflate(R.layout.follow_uplist_item, parent, null);
                holder = new Holder();

                holder.txtInIt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtInitialLetter);
                holder.txtUserName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_UserName);
                holder.txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_followDate);
                holder.txtFolloUp = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textFolloup);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
            }
```